# Full text search in MongoDB and NodeJS with text score sorting in distinct values

Tags: node.js, mongodb, full-text-search, distinct

I'm trying to implement a full text search with mongodb 3.4, nodejs and socket.io, with distinct and sorting. So far so good, i have this code that works fine but without the sorting part:

```
socket.on('searchProductName', function (data) {
    MongoClient.connect(config.database.url, function (err, db) {
        db.collection(config.database.collection.products).distinct('productName',
        {   
            $text: {$search: data}}, {score: {$meta: "textScore"}
        },
        function (err, doc) {
            socket.emit('searchProductNameResults', doc);
            db.close();
        });

    });
});
```

I'm trying to find a way to use this based on textScore sorting method, but for distinct values:

```
db.collection.find(
   <query>,
   { score: { $meta: "textScore" } }
).sort( { score: { $meta: "textScore" } } )
```

Any ideas?

Thank you

Comment: `db.collection.find({$text: {$search: "dogs"}}, {score: {$meta: "toextScore"}}).sort({score:{$meta:"textScore"}})` and create index like this `db.collection.createIndex({"key":"text","content":"text"})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the **[`aggregate()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/#db.collection.aggregate)** function in the aggregation framework to take advantage of the [text search within the **`$match`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/text-search-in-aggregation/), **[`$sort`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/#pipe._S_sort)** and **[`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group)** pipeline operators that will help you achieve the
desired result.

Take for instance the following pipeline which uses the **[`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/#pipe._S_match)** operator as the initial step and includes the **[`$text`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/text/#op._S_text)** operation. The score can be part of a **[`$sort`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/#pipe._S_sort)** pipeline specification and the preceding pipeline, **[`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group)** creates the distinct values sorted by the scores, using the **[`$addToSet`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addToSet/#grp._S_addToSet)** operator:

```
socket.on('searchProductName', function (data) {
    MongoClient.connect(config.database.url, function (err, db) {
        var pipeline = [
            { 
                "$match": {
                    "$text": {
                        "$search": data
                    }
                }
            }, 
            { "$sort": { "score": { "$meta": "textScore" } } },
            {
                "$group": {
                    "_id": null,
                    "products": { "$addToSet": "$productName" }                     
                }
            }
        ];
        db.collection(config.database.collection.products)
          .aggregate(pipeline, function (err, docs) {
                socket.emit('searchProductNameResults', docs[0].products);
                db.close();
            }
        );

    });
});
```

Comment: Please help me to `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43434299/mongodb-full-text-search-how-to-apply-extra-conditions`